# Get data from a date - 1 day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I thought this would work but its not bring back any results:

some sql statement....

```
AND (DateDiff(Day, irs.timeStamp, GETDATE()) = 1)
```

It brings back all the results for today if I change the result to 0 but not for yesterday if I change it to 1 or -1?

Comment: are you sure you have data for yesterday?

Comment: Yeah I just updated the test data and added one in and queried it for yesterday and its def there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an open-ended range, e.g. to get all data from yesterday, you want everything equal to or after midnight but before midnight today.

```
AND irs.timeStamp >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
AND irs.timeStamp < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Should work but brings back no results... Timestamp = '2012-03-06 08:23:48.370'

Comment: @Paul - And what result is `GETDATE()` giving you?. If its past 08:23:48, them it won't give you that result

Comment: I had to use GETDATE()+1); to bring back results from today as well but all works well, thanks for your help